# What's the verb version of table?

Tags: word-usage

Here we use the meaning of  "Something like an excel sheet" for table.

I want to describe "make something into a table" with one word.

Then I think I need to find the verb version of "table."

My instinct tells me that I should use *-ize* to made it a word, but I tried "taburize" and "tablize." Both failed.

Is there a single word that is the verb version of "table" or "tab"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **tab·u·lar·ize**
> tr.v.
> tab·u·lar·ized, tab·u·lar·iz·ing, tab·u·lar·iz·es
>        To put into tabular form; tabulate.

--[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tabularize)

Tabulate is much more commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

In order from most common to completely made up, some possible words are:

In typing, "tab" is short for "tabulate"; "tab stop" is short for "tabulation stop".  ASCII character code 0x9 (number 9) is the (horizontal) [tab character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters).  ASCII character code 0xB (number 11) is the rarely-used vertical tab character.

As Jim Reynolds states, "tabularize" is one verb for putting data into a tabular form.

"Tabify" is sometimes used to mean either:

- [Separate information into separate "tabs" of a user interface](https://web.archive.org/web/20160608121205/http://unwrongest.com:80/projects/tabify), or
- [Insert "tab" characters into a document](https://web.archive.org/web/20151107175334/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/14/how-to-convert-tabs-to-spaces-and-vice-versa-vstipedit0028.aspx).  Microsoft has published an application programming interface (API) that use "tabify" to convert spaces into (horizontal) tab characters.

"[Tablify](https://github.com/Stormherz/tablify)" is another verb for putting data into a tabular form.  It is even less common than "tabularize".

One proponent of [Table-Oriented Programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20160719163409/https://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TableOrientedProgramming) uses "tablize" to [mean](https://web.archive.org/web/20160709141326/http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TableOrientedGuiDiscussion) "store in table form".

If "tabbify" were a word, it would mean turning something into a "[tabby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_coat_genetics#Tabby_cats)" cat.